# Having a jQuery .click() event only fire once when inside another .click() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

If I have a jQuery .click() event firing for both "body" and a "div", how would I get it to only execute for the div and not the body when the div is clicked? Basically, I'm making my own context menu and I want clicking anywhere outside the element (in this case, "div.button") to close the menu.

Rudimentary example:

```
  $("body").click(function(event){
    if($("div.menu").is(":visible")){
      $("div.menu").hide();
    }
  });

  $("div.button").click(function(event){
    $("div.menu").show();
  });
```

As you can guess, the $("body").click() prevents/hides the menu from even showing.

A little guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

`event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Amazing how fast you people are. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to stop propagating event like this

```
$("div.button").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

than only your button will be clicked

Comment: Appreciate the help, sir. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `event.stopPropagation()` within the click element. So:

```
$( 'div.button' ).click(function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $( 'div.menu' ).show();
});
```